# How to localize Sharepoint Groups names

Tags: 2007, localization

How to localize Sharepoint Groups names?

For example, the Admin creates a group of users called "Financial Department". Can he also create at the same time the 'Departement des finances" french title of this same group, for whenever French is used, the group name will be automatically changed to its french description?

Answer (score 2):

Actually groups is one of the few kinds of content in SP2010 that are not translatable in MUI in SP2010, so AFAIK you are stuck with the language chosen when site collectionw was created.

Content that cannot be translated:
List Item Data
Permission Levels (Name, Description)
Groups (Name, About Me)
Views (Name)
OOB Web Parts
OOB Properties (Appearance, Title, etc.)
Custom Properties

Check the full list in Spence Harbars presentation from Evolution Conference:
http://www.harbar.net/presentations/spevo/DEV111%20Multi%20Lingual.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2007, you can't change the actual language of the current site, so it would never be applied.  If you are using a tool like IceFire, it handles only some of the site content, and not the settings like this one.

In SharePoint 2010, you would probably be able to activate the MUI and set the Group name in english when you are viewing the english version of the page, and set the name in french if you are using the french version of the page.  The MUI keeps track of the localized strings.  The only thing I'm not actually sure is if the groups settings are actually used as data or as settings.  If they are used as data, you won't be able to use the MUI features.

But, there is also the question : Why would you need 2 versions of a back-end value ? You should make a corporate choice to go french or english.  Those values are almost never displayed, which makes the localized versions a bit useless...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i didn't get it, can i set localized strings to group names (can i create a group and define its english description, its french description , its spanish description etc...)? if yes, how ?

Comment: You create the group, set the description, and change the language page, and then "edit" the description.  The two values entered will be kept as a value per language

Answer (score 0):

Sébastien Levert mentions IceFire.  Actually, it does handle group names, in both 2007 and 2010, and all the elements in Harbar's talk that the MUI does not already translate.

For the items that the SP2010 MUI does translate, you can also use the Export Translations link on the Site Settings page to list everything that the MUI is able to translate, in a resx format.