# Is it possible to make the sp group names localizable when created using powershell

Tags: powershell, groups, localization

I have been able to create a powershell script that creates sharepoint groups per site collection. But I need to create this groups in 2 different languages.

my question is, is it possible to make the group names localizable or translated when you create it?

I have read in one of topic in the forums that sp group names is one of the objects that Sharepoint MUI does not translate. I am not sure about this though.

here is the link of the topic i have read: [How to localize Sharepoint Groups names](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7304/how-to-localize-sharepoint-groups-names)

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have multiple, localized names for a group.  The MUI doesn't support this either (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805062(v=office.14).aspx#Section7).

Comment: thanks for the link. This is the support documentation I needed. :)